# Why do I get two different indefinate integrals for the same integrand? (u-substitution)

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

Using u-substitution I'm able to integrate the following two integrands:

$$\int \frac{1}{2x+3}dx = \frac{1}{2}\ln|2x+3|+C$$

$$\int \frac{1}{2x+5}dx = \frac{1}{2}\ln|2x+5|+C$$

Following this pattern I would assume:

$$\int \frac{1}{2x+4}dx = \frac{1}{2}\ln|2x+4|+C$$

However when I enter this expression into wolfram alpha I get:

$$\int \frac{1}{2x+4}dx = \frac{1}{2}\ln|x+2|+C$$

I can even arrive at this result myself by factoring out the $\frac{1}{2}$ before integration like this:

$$\int \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{x+2}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{x+2}dx$$

But I don't understand how this can be the case? How can two different techniques give me different results? Is there a property of logs that I don't understand?

I would think that

$$\frac{1}{2}\ln|x+2|+C \neq \frac{1}{2}\ln|2x+4|+C$$

Or are they actually equal somehow? PLEASE help me understand what's going on here.

Comment: They differ by a constant $\frac{\ln 2}2$, which gets absorbed in to $C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $$\frac{1}{2}\ln|2x+4|+C=\frac{1}{2}\ln|x+2|+\frac{1}{2}\ln2+C,$$
where $\frac{1}{2}\ln2+C$ is a constant.